# Missing Forward-slash in socket.io URI Request Causes Connection Failure

Tags: node.js, socket.io, haproxy

Sometimes, when I connect to a specific page that's performing the above client request, I see a number of `404 Not Found` errors precede by a `301 Moved Permanently` error, and after a random number of attempts (from one to four) as follows:

```
GET http://domain.com/socket.io?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1441727903280-0 404 (Not Found)
GET http://domain.com/socket.io?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1441727905168-1 404 (Not Found)
Client connected...
```

The first request I see shows the following information:

```
Request URL:http://domain.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1441728010300-0
Request Method:GET
Status Code:301 Moved Permanently
```

The proceeding requests fail with `404 Not Found` until a success occurs:

```
Request URL:http://domain.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1441728015410-2
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
```

What's strange here is that the URI specified in the network logs for any failed requests appear as follows:

**Failed**

```
http://domain.com/socket.io?EIO=3&transport=polling
```

**Success**

```
http://domain.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling
```

As you can see, it appears that the client is first attempting to connect to the URI without a trailing forward-slash; however, any concurrent successful connections contain the forward-slash.

This issue occurs at random, where sometimes it works successfully, most times it fails. It is working on my development environment successfully without issue.

I've thinned down the issue to a point where I have a simple NodeJS server which a client can connect through with socket.io, as follows:

**Client**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
     // open a socket connection
    var socket = io();

    socket.on('connect', function (user) {
        console.log('Client connected...');
    });
});
</script>
```

**Server**

```
var server = require('http').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var redis = require('redis');

server.listen(8083);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('Client connected successfully...');

  // Error reporting
  socket.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log("Socket.IO Error");
    console.log(err.stack);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    // redisClient.quit();
    console.log('Client disconnected...');
  });
});
```

*Note: I'm currently using `haproxy` which routes requests from port 80 to 8081 (HTTP) and 8083 (NodeJS).*

I've tried a lot of steps so far, so any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I attempted to connect to the IP address directly (which I thought I had previously done whilst hosted on a different web server) and found that client connects with the server immediately on the first attempt. I've therefore determined the root cause as being a redirect in my `.htaccess` file, where the naked domain is redirected to the 'www' CNAME which ultimately causes the `301 Moved Permanently` errors.